# Probability of rolling $3$ identical dice out of $6$.

Tags: probability

If $6, 6$ sided dice are rolled, what is the probability that any three are the same?

Comment: are you looking for the probability that exactly three are same or at least three are same?

Comment: At least three, sorry for not being specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability that all are same $=6\dbinom{6}{6}\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^6$

Probability that exactly $5$ are same $=6\dbinom{6}{5} \left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^5 \left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)$

Probability that exactly $4$ are same $=6\dbinom{6}{4} \left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^4 \left[\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right) \left(\dfrac{4}{6}\right)+ \left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right) \left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)\right]$

Probability that exactly $3$ are same $=6\dbinom{6}{3} \left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^3 \left[\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right) \left(\dfrac{4}{6}\right)\left(\dfrac{3}{6}\right)+ \dbinom{3}{2}\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)\left(\dfrac{4}{6}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)\right]$

Sum of the these gives required probability

Comment: For the probability that exactly $4$ are the same, you don't seem to be including cases like $(1,1,1,1,2,2)$. Similarly, for the probability that exactly $3$ are the same, you aren't including cases like $(1,1,1,2,2,3)$ or $(1,1,1,2,2,2)$.

Comment: yes, thanks for showing the error in my answer. trying to correct it.

Comment: What @JimmyK4542 said $-$ except that you are counting cases like $(1,1,1,2,2,2)$ _twice_, not zero times. This answer is very careless!

Comment: @TonyK, understood the error, trying to correct my answer

Comment: @TonyK: Actually, in the calculation for exactly $3$ being the same, it appears that he only counted the ones where the other $3$ were distinct. So $(1,1,1,2,2,2)$ would not have been counted at all.

Comment: I believe i have added the missing cases now. kindly see the edit.

Comment: I think your calculation for the probability that exactly $5$ are the same is off by a factor of $6$. Specifically, you have counted for the fact that there are $\binom{6}{5}$ ways to pick which $5$ dice are the same, but not for the fact that there are $6$ possible numbers that those $5$ dice could be. The calculations for exactly $4$ and exactly $3$ dice being the same might have similar errors.

Comment: @JimmyK4542, yes, it is. for the first case, actually it is $ 6 \times \dbinom{6}{6}$ and similar logic should have been applied for all other cases also. Admit that I am very careless, editing again to apply $6$ as the output can be any from ${1,2,\cdots,6}$